# Graphviz (DOT), different fontsizes in same label

Tags: graphviz, dot

I wonder if it is possible to use different font sizes in the same label. If so, could any provide me with example?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes this is possible using [HTML-Like labels](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html).

Here's a simple example:

```
digraph g{
    a[label=<
        <FONT POINT-SIZE="20">Bigger</FONT>
         and 
        <FONT POINT-SIZE="10">Smaller</FONT>
    >];
}
```

Output:

[image: graphviz label with different fontsizes]